# default selection not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dropdown as below

```
<select class="form-control input-xs" [(ngModel)]="filter.period" name="periodId" (ngModelChange)="onPeriodChange($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let period of periods; let i = index" [ngValue]="period.value" [selected]="i==0">
                                    {{period.text}}
     </option>
</select>
```

but it doesn't show my first element as selected in UI. It show just blank as default selected, however it renders it like

```
<select class="form-control input-xs ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" name="periodId" ng-reflect-name="periodId">
 <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}-->
    <option value="0: 0" ng-reflect-ng-value="0" ng-reflect-selected="true">
         All pending tasks
    </option>
    <option value="1: 1" ng-reflect-ng-value="1" ng-reflect-selected="false">
         Due in next 7 days
    </option>
    <option value="2: 2" ng-reflect-ng-value="2" ng-reflect-selected="false">
                                        Due next month
    </option>
    <option value="3: 3" ng-reflect-ng-value="3" ng-reflect-selected="false">
         Completed in last 7 days
    </option>
</select>
```

dropdown option in component is as below

```
periods = [{ text: 'All pending tasks', value: 0 },
       { text: 'Due in next 7 days', value: 1 },
       { text: 'Due next month', value: 2 },
       { text: 'Completed in last 7 days', value: 3 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter.coordinator` needs to be one of the instances in `periods`.

`[selected]="i==0"` is not compatible with `[ngValue]`

Comment: Really stupid mistake I made. Copied different part of the code. Updated my code.

Comment: And, [selected]="i==0" is working fine with [ngValue] in other select

Comment: I have never seen this working and I think to remember that it was mentioned in a GitHub issue that this is not supposed to work. Can you provide a Plunker that demonstrates what you state?